# Display Image (from 1 to max 6 file) into one Picturebox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, display

I'm new to C# programming, I'm doing a winforms that when entering the file name in the textbox will display the image on the picturebox. The file found can be from 1 to 6 image files, but currently the picturebox only displays one image. Can anyone tell me how to display the image file to be searched on a picturebox (the file to be searched has a maximum of 6 images), thansk for help!
my code:

```
private void bt_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  try {
    string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(FolderPath.SelectedPath);
    foreach(string file in fileNames) {
      if (file.Contains(tb1.Text)) {
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(file);
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ToString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below method (crudely) creates a new Bitmap combining all the images using their file paths and then returns that bitmap so you can assign it to a PictureBox:

```
private Bitmap MergeImages(List<string> files)
{
    var picBoxHeight = this.pictureBox1.Height;
    var picBoxWidth = this.pictureBox1.Width;

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var img = Image.FromFile(file);
        img.Dispose();
    }

    //// How many images can fit on each row
    var imagesPerRow = 6;

    //// Determine the width and height of the new image sizes based on the file count
    var width = picBoxWidth / imagesPerRow;
    var height = picBoxHeight / (files.Count / imagesPerRow); //// imagesPerRow specifies what the name explains

    //var widthMatches = picBoxWidth / 

    //// Create new Temporary Bitmap that has the width and height of the picturebox
    var generatedImage = new Bitmap(picBoxWidth, picBoxHeight);

    //// Get the Graphics for the new temporary image
    var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(generatedImage);

    //// Clear it out
    graphics.Clear(SystemColors.AppWorkspace);

    var iteration = 0;
    var rowNum = 0;

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        //// Iterate through, get the image
        var img = Image.FromFile(file);

        //// Draw the image based on the position and the order which we've iterated through
        var point = new Point(iteration * width, 0);
        graphics.DrawImage(img, iteration * width, height * rowNum, width, height);

        img.Dispose();
        iteration++;

        if (iteration % imagesPerRow == 0) //// If iteration count is divisible by the number of rows and has no remainder
                                           //// move onto new row
        {
            rowNum++;
            iteration = 0;
        }
    }

    graphics.Dispose();
    return generatedImage;
}
```

Using the method would be done like so:

```
var images = Directory.GetFiles(FolderPath.SelectedPath).ToList();

//// Filter out the files based on your search here

var combinedImage = this.MergeImages(images); //// Pass into MergeImages method
this.pictureBox1.Image = combinedImage; //// Set the `.Image` to the Bitmap generated
```

Using the Images I have in my folder, the following is my result:

[image]